# aria over html5 doesn't work in simple login example

Tags: css, html, wai-aria

I'm new to the ARIA thing and from what I've read on the internet about it nothing says something should be installed in order for this to work. I've tried a very simple example but nothing happens except pure html5 with a little css that I wrote in the style tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <h1>ARIA<h1>

    <style>
        input:focus + [role="tooltip"] {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<form action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login form</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="username">Your username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" aria-describedby="username-tip" required />
            <div role="tooltip" id="username-tip">Your username is your email address</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Your password</label>
            <input type="text" id="password" aria-describedby="password-tip" required />
            <div role="tooltip" id="password-tip">Was emailed to you when you signed up</div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong, so can someone please tell me what exactly? :D

Comment: aria doesn't really "do" anything (as far as functionality of the code).  It is used by browsers for assisted technology like screen readers.  What is it about your code above that you think is wrong?  In what way is it not working?  Perhaps a jsfiddle to so we can see it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mvgwdr43/  I wasn't sure about it, I thought using aria might make the result look different. If it is as you said, then it should be ok. Html and css look as expected, I wasn't sure what the result should have looked like regarding the fact that I wrote aria over my html :D Thank you for your answer :)